# Video editing software that will follow a subject in a cropped area of the video

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any free video editing software that will follow a subject through a cropped area of the video? A friend of mine is trying to make a video for a nonprofit and is using iPhoto but when she crops it, at certain places in the video it ends up cutting off her head. Is there software that will allow you to specify a certain object or outline in a frame of the video to remain visible while it crops?

Comment: So you want to move the frame to keep the subject on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Keyframes:
   Most a bit more advanced video editing programs have key frames, with them you say at time X, crop to Position Y. The computer will automatically fill the motion.
   Depending on the scene, this method needs a lot of work tho.
2. Tracking:
   Another way is to track the subject. That's about what you said in the question. You specify an area and the computer follows it. A freeware with this feature would be DAVINCI RESOLVE or Hitfilm. But both software require some basic knowledge of video editing.